# Display boolean and timestamp values inside react-table : React Table+ React+Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table

I am trying to print the boolean and timestamp values that are returned by some API. I am unable to do the same. Help would be appreciated

column config object:

```
    <ReactTable
                data={this.state.data}
                columns={[
                            { 
                              Header: 'Name',   
                              accessor: 'name'
                            },
                            { 
                              Header: 'Age>18',   
                              accessor: d => d.isAgeAbove18.toString(); // this does not work
                            },
                            { 
                              Header: 'TimeStamp',   
                              accessor: d => d.timeVal.toString(); // this does not work
                            },
                     ]}

    />
```

Comment: Will this work for you `d => d.isAgeAbove18 ? "YES" : "NO"` ?

Comment: @euvs No ! This one did not work

Comment: @euvs your suggestion did works, was just passing by and saw vr12 saying no. Btw i had `id` prop besides `Header` & `accessor`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looking at the React tables documentation, it says that you need to provide the id property whenever the accessor type is not a string. So, I the updated format should be this.

```
columns={[
          { 
           Header: 'Name',   
           accessor: 'name'
          },
          { 
           id:'age'                  // add this
           Header: 'Age>18',   
           accessor: d => d.isAgeAbove18.toString();
          },
          { 
           id: 'timestamp'           // add this
           Header: 'TimeStamp',   
           accessor: d => d.timeVal.toString();
          },
         ]}
```

Comment: In order to avoid the "Property does not exist on type 'object'" error, you might need to explicitly cast the column object to "any", e.g.
`accessor: (d: any) => d.isAgeAbove18.toString();`

See [this React-Table issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/22947) and [the related PR thread](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/22977#issuecomment-360194117) for discussions around this.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the best solution in case you are using filters,

```
id: 'available',
Header: "Available",
accessor: d => { return d.available ? 'Available' : 'Not available' },
filterable: true,
Filter: () => (
  <select className='form-control' value={this.state.availability_value} onChange={(e) => this.applyFilter(e.target.value)} >
    <option value={`{ "available": "" }`}>Select</option>
    <option value={`{ "available": "" }`}>All</option>
    <option value={`{ "available": "1" }`}>Available</option>
    <option value={`{ "available": "0" }`}>Not available</option>
  </select>
)
```